# prevent validaton onfocusout depending of the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having problem to validate the form below.
The main issue is that I have to use the "onfocusout" function to validate the inputs.
The name input has be required depending of the radio selection.
When the "value3" is selected, the focus is set to the input.
While on the input, if the user tries to change the radio button, the onfocusout is triggered before the radio value is changed, and in that case the error is shown while it should not
Any suggestion?

```
<form id="myform">    

  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="value1" /> value1
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="value2" /> value2
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="value3" /> value3

  <input type="text" name="name" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The js code is:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    return $("input[name='radio']:checked").val() == "value3";
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "You must enter name"
        }
    },
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        this.element(element);
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('success');
        return false;
    }
});

$("input[name='radio']").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "value3") $("input[name='name']").focus();
    else $("input[name='name']").valid();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/954ros6L/

Comment: Why do you need to use focusout?

Comment: @RubenSerrate because if a required input is skipped by the user the input must be marked as invalid

Comment: Why not check the inputs when the users submits the form and mark them as invalid then? Then you would only see the error when you submit the form, what if a user wants to fill the input later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `.valid()` method too late.  Simply call it every time you `change` the radio buttons and the timing will be correct.

```
$("input[name='radio']").on('change', function () {
    $("input[name='name']").valid();  // <- move it to here
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == "value3") {
        $("input[name='name']").focus();
    }
});
```

Plus, if you notice, the validation message now correctly appears when the field is invalid.

You also do not need a custom `onfocusout` handler.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/954ros6L/4/**

---

Sidenote:

You cannot use `event.preventDefault()` inside just any callback function since `event` is not a valid argument for the function.  Besides, [`.preventDefault()` is only meant to block the default action of an `event`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), like stopping the page jump after an anchor `click`, etc. ... not the default behavior of a plugin.

To change the default behavior of `onfocusout` simply means that you write a function to override the plugin's default behavior, which you've already done.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following to prevent to normal event handlers

event.preventDefault();